# In a java application, if all 3 log4j APIs exists in the classpath, how to choose one of them to be effective?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, classpath, log4j2

In a Cloudera Spark-on-YARN installation, I encounter an application that has multiple log4j APIs in its classpath:

- log4j:1.2
- log4j-1.2-api:2.x
- log4j-core:2.x

When the application is launched. I found the following error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

It cannot be fixed because the vendor of the platform exclusively used the log4j:1.2 configuration everywhere: it has integrated a managed log4j.properties file (not the log4j2.properties), which is in the classpath, used by many components, and cannot be tampered.

How do I tell the classloader or log4j implementation to not trying to find log4j2 file if it is missing?

**UPDATE 1**: I've tried the following Spark arguments to customise the driver JVM. Effects are as follows:

- `--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC -Dlog4j1.compatibility=true -Dlog4j.configuration=./conf_5/log4j.properties -Dlog4j.debug"`

result is:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
log4j: setFile called: /tmp/spark-b190d9df-64bf-4ff6-b72d-2cb8de1d888a/__driver_logs__/driver.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Finalizing appender named [_DriverLogAppender].
```

- `--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC -Dlog4j1.compatibility=true -Dlog4j.configurationFile=./conf_5/log4j.properties -Dlog4j.debug"`

result is:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
log4j: setFile called: /tmp/spark-817bc6eb-bcc0-4cee-ba32-dbd4d89048e5/__driver_logs__/driver.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Finalizing appender named [_DriverLogAppender].
```

So none of them is working properly. There seems to be no way to either use the right version or use the wrong configuration file

Comment: Try removing `log4j` and add `-Dlog4j1.compatibility=true` to the JVM options.

Comment: "Try removing log4j" that's also not possible: Spark is a distributed computing framework which has to preload log4j:1.2 on executor nodes

Comment: Then `-Dlog4j1.compatibility=true` will at least configure Log4j 2.x using the Log4j 1.x config. Whether `log4j` or `log4j-1.2-api` will be used to log will up to the classloader order roulette.

Comment: No it doesn't, still the same error, I also added "-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" but none of them work

Comment: You did not mention what master and deploy mode you're using, but if it is "yarn" and "cluster", have you distributed your log4j configuration file using `--files` option? 
Please also note that statement _"...It cannot be fixed because the vendor of the platform exclusively used the log4j:1.2 configuration everywhere..."_ is not entirely accurate -- upstream ASF Spark itself uses a mix of 1.x and 2.x logging and was just recently migrated to log4j 2.x (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37814). The Vendor is still using old 2.4 Spark version in its distro.